# Can momenta eigenstate written in term of $x$ be an eigenfunction of position?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform

Being non-commuatable operators, momentum and position cannot have simultaneous eigenfunctions. But in "Theoretical Minimum: QM" by Lenny Susskind and Artsy Friedman, in explaining Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle: [image]

I don't understand why they assume that the eigenstate of momentum (Psi with subscript p) is going to have a localized poistion component. I would love some clarification on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what your objection is.
Actually the given eigenstate of momentum $\psi_p(x)$
is as **de**localized as it can be, since $|\psi_p(x)|^2$
has the same value for all $x$.

Comment: Wowza! I interpreted Lenny's words wrong. Thanks for pointing out that delocalization part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse different things. An eigenstate of p or x is defined with the equation 
$A \psi = \lambda \psi$, where A is the momentum/position operator and $\lambda$ the corresponding eigenvalue. Psi here is an abstract mathematical element of the QM Hilbert space. What you have written down here as $\psi_p(x)$ is an eigenstate of the momentum operator in the x representation. It is a specific representation of the Hilbert space vector, but not an eigenstate of the x operator.

Comment: Haha yh! What Lenny was trynna show was that eigenstate of momenta is perfectly delocalized in terms of position ( being 1/2pi for all x values). I thought momenta itself was delocalized. Thanks for pointing out  that "ψp(x)  is an eigenstate of the momentum operator in the x representation"! That was really helpful!

Comment: Ah okay, so it was just a missed formulation :)